# Efficient sum of expensive rolling window products

Tags: algorithm, math, numeric, discrete-mathematics

Given a sequence of numbers a[i] for i = 0 to N-1, I'm trying to calculate the following sum:

```
a[0] * a[1] * a[2] +
a[1] * a[2] * a[3] +
a[2] * a[3] * a[4] +
...
a[N-4] * a[N-3] * a[N-2] +
a[N-3] * a[N-2] * a[N-1]
```

I'd like to make the size G of a multiplied group (in the example above 3) a variable parameter. Then, the result can be naively obtained using a simple O(N*G) algorithm, which can be written in pseudocode like so:

```
sum = 0
for i from 0 to (N-G-1):
  group_contribution = 1
  for j from 0 to (G-1):
    group_contribution *= a[i+j]
  sum += group_contribution
```

However, for large G's it is obvious that this algorithm is terribly inefficient, especially assuming that numbers of the sequence a[i] aren't known in advance and have to be expensively calculated at runtime.

For this reason, I've considered using the following algorithm of complexity O(N+G) which recycles the values of the sequence a[i] by calculating a rolling product:

```
sum = 0
rolling_product = 1
for i from 0 to (G-1):
  rolling_product *= a[i]
sum += rolling_product
for i from G to (N-1):
  rolling_product /= a[i-G]
  rolling_product *= a[i]
  sum += rolling_product
```

I'm however concerned about numerical stability of division in standard floating-point representation.

I'd be interested in knowing if there is a stable, faster way to calculate this sum. It feels like a basic numerical task to me, yet currently I'm at a loss how do it efficiently.

Thank you for any ideas!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if you compute the reverse partial products carefully, you don't need to divide.

```
def window_products(seq, g):
    lst = list(seq)
    reverse_products = lst[:]
    for i in range(len(lst) - 2, -1, -1):
        if i % g != len(lst) % g:
            reverse_products[i] *= reverse_products[i + 1]
    product = 1
    for i in range(len(lst) - g + 1):
        yield reverse_products[i] * product
        if i % g == len(lst) % g:
            product = 1
        else:
            product *= lst[i + g]


print(list(window_products(range(10), 1)))
print(list(window_products(range(10), 2)))
print(list(window_products(range(10), 3)))
```

Answer (score 3):

As a preamble, you could consider running some test cases on both algorithms and compare the results (as a relative error, for example).

Next, if you have the additional memory and time, here is a stable approach in O(*N* log<sub>2</sub> *G*) time and memory. It is similar to the approach in constant time, linearithmic space to the [range minimum query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query#Solution_using_constant_time_and_linearithmic_space) problem.

**Precomputing products of power-of-two ranges**

Let *B*[*i*][*j*] be the product of 2<sup>*j*</sup> elements of *a* starting at position *i*, so

*B*[*i*][*j*] = *a*[*i*] × *a*[*i* + 1] × ... × *a*[*i* + 2<sup>*j*</sup> - 1]

We are interested in *N* log<sub>2</sub> *G* values in *B*, namely those for 0 ≤ *j* ≤ log<sub>2</sub> *G*. We can compute each of these values in O(1), since

*B*[*i*][*j*] = *B*[*i*][*j* - 1] × *B*[*i* + 2<sup>*j* - 1</sup>][*j* - 1]

**Computing the sum**

To compute one term in the sum, we decompose *G* into power-of-two sized chunks. For example, if G = 13, then the first term is

*a*[0] × ... × *a*[12] = (*a*[0] × ... × *a*[7]) × (*a*[8] × ... × *a*[11]) × *a*[12] = *B*[0][3] × *B*[8][2] × *B*[12][0]

Each of the O(*N*) terms can be computed in O(log<sub>2</sub> *G*) time, thus the total complexity of finding the sum is O(*N* log<sub>2</sub> *G*).

Answer (score 0):

Your rolling product is a good idea, but it has problems with stability as you say.  I would fix that this way:

- Separately use a similar system to keep track of the number of zeros and negative numbers.  Those are integer sums, so no stability problem.
- Instead of calculating a rolling product of all `a[i]`, calculate a rolling *sum* of `log(abs(a[i]))`, excluding zeros.  Then when you need the product it's `(num_zeros > 0 ? 0.0 : exp(log_sum)) * sign`.  That'll take care of the major instability.
- While you're generating output from your clever rolling log_sum algorithm, you should simultaneously be building a *fresh* log_sum from which you haven't subtracted anything.  When the number of elements in that fresh sum gets to `G`, then overwrite your rolling llog_sum with that number and reset it to zero.  This will remove any rounding errors that would accumulate over the long term.

Comment: It seems to me that rolling product with division will be a more stable algorithm than log and exponentiation in terms of accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new sequence b where b[0] = a[0] * a[1] * a[2] * ... a[G-1] etc.

Now you have a simpler problem where to calculate the sum of the b values you can maintain a total and each time you add a value you subtract b[0] and add the new value and slide them all down one (using circular buffer so nothing moves). [Typical sliding window moving average type code]

Keep a cache of the last G a[] values and calculating the new value to add to the end is just O(G) operations and you only ever calculate a[i] once.